# Unzip problems in Gitlab CI pipeline

Tags: terraform, gitlab-ci, unzip, alpine-linux

I have a simple step with Gitlab CI to install Terraform on an Alpine based image:

```yaml
step_1:
  stage: stage_x
  image: alpine/doctl:latest
  script:
    - wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/1.2.8/terraform_1.2.8_linux_amd64.zip
    - unzip terraform_1.2.8_linux_amd64.zip
    - mv terraform /usr/bin/terraform
    - terraform version
```

When executed, I have this error from the unzip command:

> unzip: 'terraform' exists but is not a regular file

I tried this command over the same image in my machine and it works fine.
Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you use the destination option of unzip: `unzip terraform_1.2.8_linux_amd64.zip -d /usr/bin` and drop the `mv` totally?

Comment: But basically what the error there is telling you is that there is already a `terraform` in that container, and that It is not a regular file, so, probably a folder or a symlink

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε, I checked if in my local with there are a folder or symlink but it doesn't exist. And, the commands work well here with the same image. Over unzip in destination folder solved finlally the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One way to overcome your issue is to use the `-d` option of `unzip` in order to unzip Terraform in the folder */usr/bin* directly:

> -d DIR    Extract into DIR

<sup>*Source: `unzip --help`*</sup>

This way, you can also drop the `mv` line totally.

So, your step becomes:

```yaml
step_1:
  stage: stage_x
  image: alpine/doctl:latest
  script:
    - wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/1.2.8/terraform_1.2.8_linux_amd64.zip
    - unzip terraform_1.2.8_linux_amd64.zip -d /usr/bin
    - terraform version
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in CI, the Gitlab runner is checking out your code which already has a `terraform` folder. This makes the call to `unzip` to fail because it already finds the folder with the same name `terraform` pre-existing.